# Can I get the error code from Twilio server response?

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the [instructions](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html) provided by Twilio to send SMS messages from a Google Sheet. I'm using the `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)` to make the post request. Currently it's catching any errors and logging it to a cell.

```
for (i in data) {
   var row = data[i];
   try {
     response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
     status = "Sent";
   } catch(err) {
     status = "Error";      
}
sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 4).setValue(status);
```

}

The `err` is quite long `Exception: Request failed for https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/twilio SID/Messages.json returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code": 21211, "message": "The 'To' number ##### is not a valid phone number.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "stat... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`.

Is it possible to get just the code value? In the example above, that would be `21211`.  I'd like to show the user, but in more user friendly language.

I have tried to use the `getContentText()` as [documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText()) but couldn't get it to return anything.

Comment: Have you tried ``muteHTTPExceptions`` > ``getContentText()`` > ``JSON.parse()['code']``?

Comment: Muting the exceptions does work, I can then get the JSON objects with `var a = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())`.  From here I'll just have to manually throw an error depending on response.